# Autopopulate firstname field not working

Tags: infopath

I tried autopopulate field using SOAP web service. When I preview, the field is still empty. I don't know where I am lacking.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you did?

Comment: Please have a look - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cho6zvkc2psaf7/rule.png?dl=0